# Portable linux system

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

So basically I want to have a Linux system on an external hard drive along with the grub on another partition (which would be bootable).

The problem is that I still want to use my hard drive as a storage device. So what I did is to make four partitions:

- storage (FAT32);
- Linux (EXT4);
- EFI (FAT32) and
- Swap.

The installation worked fine, I managed to boot on the Linux system once but as soon as I unplugged the drive, the boot entry `UEFI : hard_drive` was no longer appearing in the EFI system configuration boot menu, and my computer does not have an option to boot directly from the *grubx64.efi* file.
I'm running out of idea now so does anyone have the solution?

Comment: It should be simple to create a standard [Portable Linux](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-portable-linux-os-distros-to-install-run-from-usb/) boot media and then resize the Linux partition and create your data partition.

Comment: Or see *How to Create a Live Ubuntu USB Drive With Persistent Storage*, https://www.howtogeek.com/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/